# Call UIAlertController From IBAction Button

Tags: swift3

I am trying to call an AlertController to display a message to the user once a Post has been made to my PHP site. I am having trouble calling the AlertController inside the IBAction Button. Thanks in advance for the help. I'm sure I am just missing something basic.

Here is a snippet of my code..

```
//Button Press Function
@IBAction func UPDATE_BTN(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let SSID = SSID_INPUT.text
    let PASS = PASS_INPUT.text

    //Call SSID and PASS Valid to Check Length
    let ssid_return = isSSIDValid(SSID!)
    let pass_return = isPasswordValid(PASS!)

    //If They Pass, Then Send to Web Server
    if(ssid_return && pass_return)
    {
    print("Valid, Sending Info")
    //Send Info to Webserver to Update Info
    SEND_POST(SSID: SSID!,PASS: PASS!)


    //This is where I want to call the ALERT....
    func viewDidAppear(_: animated: Bool){
            CreateAlert(title: "TEST", message: "IT WENT THROUGH")
        }


    }

    //Otherwise Send User Error
    else {

   //Also Call Another Alert Here To Say It Didn't Post...

        print("Not Valid")
    }


}
```

And here is the code for my AlertController

```
//Alert Function
func CreateAlert (title:String, message:String){

    let Alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

    Alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: {(ACTION) in
        Alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    }))

    self.present(Alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

Comment: don't start let or var names in Capitalised. let Alert be let alert

Comment: Heard. Will change the code. But how do I call the alert function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your CreateAlert func like below

```
func CreateAlert(title: String, message: String) {

        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message:
            message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default,handler: nil))

        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: This is a cleaner example, now how do I call the function to display the alert? Am I doing it right by calling the func viewDidAppear?

Comment: Nevermind I got it. I was trying to call the function before it was created.smh Thanks for the help!